# how to share resource or data from 1 micro service with another microservice which shares common db in node js

Tags: node.js, database, model, dependencies, microservices

I am using microservice architecture which shares a common database. Here i have two Microservices in first one i have defined users related model like users, userImage, userAddress, etc and in second microservice i want to access all this data what is the best way to do it. I am using nodejs and sequelize orm

I have copied those models in second microservices and then fetching the user details. But this way i am not having updated models in all microservice. and I also don't want to depend on first MS response so I am avoiding axios call or any internal call to other MS.

Comment: Why do you even have separate microservices?

Comment: I was planning to use all the user related activities separate from other microservice in this I am handling all order related activities like placing orders. And here at this point I require user details in Order microservice. Any suggestions?

Comment: Publishing domain events from the user microservice for consumption by the order microservice would be my suggestion.  If two microservices share the same database (meaning reading and writing the same tables), you are always better off just making them one microservice.